# in selenium python , when test alone the test pass with another test the test fail

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, pytest

i have a project in python to test a website

i do test like so :

```py
def test_start_here_menu():
     website_get()
     start_here_menu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="menu-item-74654"]/a')
     start_here_menu.click()
     start_here_logo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="post-68110"]/header/div/div/h1')
     assert start_here_logo.is_displayed()
```

IF i run this test alone, its a Pass.
however,if another test is also active like

```py
def test_pantry():
 website_get()
 pantry_menu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="menu-item-74656"]/a')
 pantry_menu.click()
 pantry_logo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="primary"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/h1/span')
 assert pantry_logo.is_displayed()
```

only the first test is successful, every other test after it fails.
if i do the second test alone its a Pass to

can you help my figure out why?

only the first test is successful others fail
but individually every test works

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about Python, but if your method call to `website_get()` is being called concurrently (every test at the same time) but is only meant to be called sequentuelly it could be the reason only one test is running succesfully.

Are you using a test runner to manage test execution? Example:

```py
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create a new Firefox session
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        # navigate to the application home page
        self.driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

    def test_start_here_menu(self):
        start_here_menu = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu-item-74654"]/a'
        )
        start_here_menu.click()
        start_here_logo = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//*[@id="post-68110"]/header/div/div/h1'
        )
        assert start_here_logo.is_displayed()

    def test_pantry(self):
        pantry_menu = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu-item-74656"]/a'
        )
        pantry_menu.click()
        pantry_logo = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//*[@id="primary"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/h1/span'
        )
        assert pantry_logo.is_displayed()

    def tearDown(self):
        # close the browser window
        self.driver.quit()
```

**UPDATE**

Okay I downloaded a Python IDE installed it and manually tested the below, and it is 100% working, it does take a couple of secs to launch the new browser between tests, but it works just fine. Each browser session is opened on it's own and then is closed when each test is done. I would suggest really reviewing your code and looking at your `website_get` method as the problem is most certianly on your side, the below works perfectly.

```py
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create a new Chrome session
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        # navigate to the application home page
        self.driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/")

    def test_start_here_menu(self):
        english_wiki_link = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//*[@class="central-featured-lang lang1"]'
        )
        english_wiki_link.click()
        english_wiki_url = self.driver.current_url
        assert english_wiki_url.__eq__("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")

    def test_pantry(self):
        german_wiki_link = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//*[@class="central-featured-lang lang4"]'
        )
        german_wiki_link.click()
        german_wiki_link = self.driver.current_url
        assert german_wiki_link.__eq__("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite")

    def tearDown(self):
        # close the browser window
        self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: it's not working, even if im using. GET individually the browser stay open and not closing before reopening in a new test.

Comment: Please see my updated example, there are no problems with the code.